# How to Get Shadow Dom to Work With A LIst?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, shadow-dom

I am using Polymer to play around with the shadow dom. I have what I feel like should be a simple use case that I can't quite get working. I want define a "nav" container that can contain nav links. I'd like it to look like the following:

```
<top-nav>
  <nav-link href="#a">A</nav-link>
  <nav-link href="#b">B</nav-link>
  <nav-link href="#c">C</nav-link>
  <nav-link href="#d">D</nav-link>
</top-nav>
```

The following are the definitions that I created for the two elements (using Bootstrap theme-ing for style):

```
<polymer-element name="top-nav" noscript>
  <template>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <content></content>
    </ul>
  </template>
</polymer-element>

<polymer-element name="nav-link" attributes="href" noscript>
  <template>
    <li><a href="{{ href }}"><content></content></a></li>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

Inspecting the Shadow Dom, both element seem to work independently - the `top-nav` creates a `ul` and the `nav-link` creates a `li` containing an `a`. The problem is that the `li`'s to not seem to be children of the `ul`. What am I missing here?

Comment: `nav` is not a valid custom element name. There needs to be a dash in the name (e.g. `x-nav`, `my-nav`, etc).

Comment: @ebidel Good catch. Changed to `top-nav`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `li` elements are owned by `nav-link`. There is no way to make `nav-link` disappear in this setup, so your tree looks like:

```
<top-nav>
  <ul>
    <nav-link>
      <li>
    ...
```

Instead you can make your `nav-link` **is-a** `li` (instead of **has-a**), and resolve this problem.

1. make Definition of `nav-link` extend `li`

`<polymer-element name="nav-link" extends="li" attributes="href" noscript>`

1. use type-extension syntax when making `nav-link`

`<li is="nav-link" href="#a">A</li>`

Here it is all put together:
http://jsbin.com/vecil/2/edit

Comment: This appears to address the issue, thanks! Any idea why the text of the shadow-dom anchor is not clickable?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading the question correctly, I think the core issue is that Bootstrap's CSS is written like this:

```
.nav-tabs > li
```

And you're trying to recreate that, but given your current structure the shadow boundaries prevent it. If you stick with your current setup then you'll need to rewrite those bootstrap selectors so they look like this:

```
.nav-tabs ::content nav-link::shadow li
```

But that is probably not what you want :) If you went down that route then you'd end up rewriting Bootstrap. That highlights a very important point: Bootstrap was written before tools like Shadow DOM existed so it doesn't always port easily.

Until we have the next generation of UI frameworks written with Shadow DOM in mind I think there will occasionally be situations like this where it may be easier to just create your own elements that borrow the Bootstrap styles. Trying to cobble together Shadow DOM that exactly matches their selectors is probably more effort than its worth.